# Should pre-boot SATA drivers be 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: windows, boot, drivers

In the past when I've downloaded preboot drivers for use with F6 during a Windows Installation (for SATA drivers for instance), I've always just seen a single set of driver files. The Intel drivers I just downloaded have both 32 and 64 bit versions of the drivers and the instructions don't make it clear which set are used for the F6 disk.

Since these are PRE-boot drivers, does the 32 vs 64 bit even come into play? Which of the drivers would I use? The fact that other F6 driver downloads only have one set of files makes me think that the preboot environment is 32 bit only. But is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Pre-boot" simply means they get initialized earlier than the rest. They, however, still run as part of Windows, and must match the Windows kernel architecture.

Answer (score 1):

If both the drivers are in the same oem folder, then just leave them all intact. Otherwise, for xp, use the 32-bit drivers, as I assume you are installing xp 32-bit.

Comment: The drivers are in separate folders. And I'm not installing XP necessarily. More likely either x86 or x64 versions of Win7. Part of why I was asking was to find out whether the preboot environment can be either 32 or 64 bit. I did find an alternate (unofficial) download source for the Intel SATA drivers and compared them to the official files and the unofficial version used the x64 drivers. Since it's an unofficial source I'm not sure how much that means though.

Comment: Ah, ok. The reference to F6 made me assume Windows XP, as Vista or above do driver-loading differently.